# Handling null in fields of JSF page in Oracle ADF

Tags: javascript, null, oracle-adf

Can I know whether a field's(or a component's) value is 'null' or not in Oracle ADF.?
I have unchecked 'Mandatory' in EO.xml(It's required for us as per the application to un-check that option) and in JSF page (when I run the application) I'm clicking on 'Commit' without entering any text in all the fields, I thought like it should not allow me to Commit as I didn't entered any text. But it's getting Committed without saying any sort of error.

So, my question here is, can I stop it(***Committing Without entering text in the fields***), if anybody knows please help me..
And
Can I get out of this problem by using JavaScript.?

Answer (score 0):

If the field is not set to be mandatory why should ADF stop you from getting empty data into that field?
You could add your own validator to the field to check if the value is empty instead - but that would basically be the same as turning mandatory on.

Comment: Hi Shay, thanks for your response.

Of-course I agree, but sometimes we have to handle some fields values (which are to be entered by the users). And there is no Mandatory option on those fields in EO. But we need those values for some calculations. So I asked this question to handle such cases.

Comment: If you want to check if the field is empty, then overwrite the EO's doDML method and introduce your own checks before the actual execution against the DB.